# Is there an adjective for having and spitting lots of saliva, especially in a state of wild, raging abandon?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that describes this happy fellow:

[image: this happy fellow]
<sup>*source*: imgur.com</sup>

I don't think *frothing* is the right word. It isn't froth or foam, but sticky wads of spit.

Comment: There is the aphorism, *Say it, don't spray it!*

Comment: Having just absent-mindedly clicked on the link, I can also add that it doesn’t lead anywhere—the address bar just goes empty and no page loads (at least in Safari), which just makes the link all the more suspicious-looking.

Comment: I'd say that man is ***foaming at the mouth*** (or, if he had also just developed an incapacitating fear of water), ***rabid***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the server itself is owned by Google, and is used for photo storage. Still, not being a regular image link is annoying. Firefox asks me to download something called unnamed.webp, which doesn't seem legit.

Comment: @MattЭллен WebP is a lossless image format created by Google… and so far, supported by nobody else. The link works in Chrome, but not FF or IE, for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word [*slobbering*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+slobber) comes to mind.

More often used to describe the drooling of a dog but is perfectly acceptable for the picture given.

Comment: Slobbering has more a connotation of sloppy, unwonted drooling—not in the sense of wild, raging abandon that the OP means. A better answer is given below by Oldcat.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a dictionary citation and definition.

Answer (score 28):

**Slavering** - defined as to let saliva run from the mouth

source - google's dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[To drool](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drool): (from TFD)

> - To let saliva or liquid spill out from the mouth.

Could Anger cause Excessive saliva ([Drooling](http://www.ehealthme.com/cs/anger/excessive+saliva))?

Source: www.ehealthme.com

Comment: Just a medical fyi. Anger activates the sympathetic branch of the autonomous nervous system which diminishes salivary flow; relaxing (parasympathetic branch) increases it. Angry people spit because they're too busy screaming to swallow the saliva that they do have.

Comment: [Saliva and the Control of Its Secretion](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642178863-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1346459-p174093370&ei=M4sPVOvbCYKKyAT9_YKwCg&usg=AFQjCNEaN4bjWOk0VN6oSmq0map2XqD5Hw&sig2=Bcqjz5Ih_602yBJiFkpq_g&bvm=bv.74649129,d.aWw) section 8.

Comment: @medica - nice description!! Wouldn't it fit the picture shown?

Comment: Yes, it would. This was kind of a response to your offering of *could anger cause excessive saliva*. I'm glad you weren't offended by my comment. :) I did not want to offend.

Comment: @medica - I do appreciate it..thanks for your contribution :))

Answer (score 1):

*Spittling* works as a rare present participle of *spittle*, most often used to refer to spit when ejecting from the mouth.

Sources: Googling "define spittle" gives the definition, "saliva, especially as ejected from the mouth." I believe Google get their definitions from the Oxford English Dictionary.

Also, the *spittling* form: [WordSense](http://www.wordsense.eu/spittling/); [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spittling)

Answer (score 1):

We often use the verb:

> splutter

... to indicate someone spitting whilst speaking loudly, aggressively or when very emotional. Here's the link to the word in the Google dictionary: [spluttering](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_en-gbGB482GB482&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spluttering)

Answer (score 0):

Try GLEEK. It refers to the squirt of saliva ejected involuntarily when you open your mouth. Most common when you are salivating over food expected to be special but I think in this instance it fits.

https://www.google.com/search?q=gleek
Link brings up several pages of information.

Comment: Is this a regional word? I've never heard of it nor is it in my dictionary. Please add a dictionary reference so that others can verify this word is used.

Answer (score -3):

If you are open to more medical-sounding terms,

> [sialorrhea](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sialorrhea)
>
> [ptyalism](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ptyalism)
>
> [hypersalivation](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hypersalivation)
>
> [drooling](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/drooling)

all refer to the excessive flow of saliva.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a dictionary citation and definition.

Comment: it's bureaucratic pedantry like you display here which so often dissuades even marginally creative suggestions .

Comment: The [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) is a good place to start, along with [other material in the Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and the [FAQs on Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: You should feel free to join the [Meta discussion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/whats-up-with-all-these-dictionary-reference-edits) about using dictionaries to answer questions.